# How to filter rows where a column A cell value is not part of a pattern of values from other rows?

Tags: excel, design-patterns, excel-formula

I need to filter a column that contains a pattern of the numbers 1-5 in individual cells in the column.  If the 1-5 pattern is broken, I need to hide the offending cells.  Is there a built in feature or do I need to make a VBA macro?

[image: Example]

Comment: Is it acceptable to make a helper column and filter on it?

Comment: Sure!  The sheet is hundreds of lines long and I am only interested in seeing the rows where the 1 2 3 4 5 pattern is adhered to.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't mind the Dutch equivalent to `TRUE` and `FALSE` (`WAAR` & `ONWAAR`), but you could use:

```
=CONCAT(INDEX(A:A,ROW()-(A2-1)):INDEX(A:A,ROW()+(5-A2)))="12345"
```

[image]

I used headers, to prevent error on row parsing in the formula. And you might want to use IFERROR to prevent errors when your first value is a 5 for example.

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
=(A1>=1)*(A1<=5)*PRODUCT(--(INDEX(A:A,N(IF({1},{1,2,3,4,5}-A1+ROW())))={1,2,3,4,5}))
```

[image]